# How to use unlink in Windows 7?

Tags: php, windows-7

I have a problem when using unlink in my Win 7 machine. This is my code in getFile.php

```
$file_name = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\fw\tmp\my_file.php';
$myfile = fopen($file_name , 'a');
unlink(''.$file_name );
```

everytime I execute the code, i get an error message

**Warning: unlink(C:\xampp\htdocs\fw\tmp\my_file.php) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\fw\libraries\getFile.php on line 79**

Anybody has a solution ?

Thanks before,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cann't remove files that are opened

```
$file_name = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\fw\tmp\my_file.php';
$myfile = fopen($file_name , 'a');
..
fclose($myfiles);
..
unlink(''.$file_name );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$file_name = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\fw\tmp\my_file.php';
$myfile = fopen($file_name , 'a');
unlink(''.$file_name );
```

You cannot delete file using this

first you need to close that file

using

```
fclose($myfiles);
```

and use

```
$filename="myfile.php";  
unlink("../../../../"$filename);
```

you cannot delete using `c:\xamp....` or `http:\\file\files.php`

Answer (score 0):

i am using windows 10 and xampp , this worked for ,

```
unlink(pathinfo(realpath($file_name), PATHINFO_DIRNAME).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_name);
```