# Removing file in haskell

Tags: windows, haskell

I am trying to delete a text file in haskell while working in winhugs with help of removeFile function.But it is giving an error that

```
Program error: price.txt: Directory.removeFile: permission denied
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: This might be a windows "problem" - are you sure you have OS-level permission to delete the file? It might be owned by someone else, be read-only, etc...

Comment: No..i am the admin.But i dont know if their are permission issues in haskell.That we have to explicitly define them

Comment: Is their any way to clear the whole file contents if i cant remove it..?

Comment: Are you sure the file is not opened by another process? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650777/how-to-use-unlink-in-windows-7

Comment: Ya,..its not opened..but giving the error..can i clear all its content if i cant remove it..?

Comment: Not sure, if you can't delete it Windows probably will not let you edit it either. You could always try and see what happens, though.

Comment: @user3001932 Open it for writing and write an empty string to it. That clears it.

Comment: @kqr..plz explain a bit..thanx in advance

Comment: @user3001932 Actually, it's even simpler than I thought. Just opening the file (for writing) and then closing it again will clear it (not remove it!) This also mirrors the underlying system interface. Which part are you getting stuck on?

Comment: Did you _create_ the file using Haskell by any chance? If so, it's possible that WinHugs itself is what's holding the file open in the first place...

Answer (score 4):

According to the Hackage Docs for [`removeFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.0.1/docs/System-Directory.html#v%3aremoveFile), the operation may fail with:

> isPermissionError / PermissionDenied The process has insufficient privileges to perform the operation. [EROFS, EACCES, EPERM]

Also, according to the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.0.1/docs/src/System-Directory.html#removeFile) there, `removeFile` is just a thin wrapper around `deleteFile` in the Win32 API:

```
removeFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
removeFile path =
#if mingw32_HOST_OS
  Win32.deleteFile path
#else
  Posix.removeLink path
#endif
```

---

**Update**

After digging around the source code for winhugs, it seems the Windows API function `unlink` is actually being used to delete a file in Hugs:

```
primFun(primRemoveFile) { /* remove a file     */
  int rc;
  String s = evalName(IOArg(1));

  if (!s) {
    IOFail(mkIOError(NULL,
             nameIllegal,
             "Directory.removeFile",
             "illegal file name",
             &IOArg(1)));
  }

   rc = unlink(s);

  if (rc != 0)
    throwErrno("Directory.removeFile", TRUE, NO_HANDLE, &IOArg(1));
  IOReturn(nameUnit);
}
```

In any case, the previous answer is going to hold up in the sense that any permissions constraint is not introduced by Haskell. Rather, any permissions error would be due to the underlying OS environment (user accounts, open files, permissions, etc).

Comment: You don't, I just wanted to point out what is happening under the hood is just a simple OS-level delete operation.